# Regular expression: convert to positive

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not familiar with regular expressions. I bumped into the following code, which should allow both negative and positive values. The current function automatically converts negative to positive values.

```
    parseInputNum: function(val){ 
        var sep = val.lastIndexOf('.') > val.lastIndexOf(',')? '.' : ','; 
        var arr = val.replace(new RegExp('[^\\d'+sep+']+', 'g'), '').match(new RegExp('(\\d+(?:['+sep+']\\d+|))$')); 
        return arr? arr[1].replace(/[,]/g, '.') : false; 
    }
```

I'll be honest in the fact that I am not familiar with regular expressions.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Well, my question is how the regular expression can be converted to avoid the automatic conversion from negative to positive values. The function is executed 'on blur' on a text field, and when typing a negative number, it turns into a positive. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a problem wiith simply removing it from being called during `onBlur`, given that its functionality is no longer desired?

Comment: Actually there is, because the other rules of the regex are supposed to stay. I didn't write the rule, and I'm not familiar with regex, so unfortunately I'm unable the make this small adaptation. (Actually, business users noticed this mistake during the testing).

Comment: Quite strange to use a regex to make numbers positive :S. First parsing them to an integer/double will in most cases be more efficient, at least when you want to perform operations on the input...

Comment: If you have an alternative to the preceding function, that's always welcome. As for me, I need to fulfill a list of requirements, and this is one I got stuck with due to my lack of knowledge on regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below piece is what removes the negative signs:

```
val.replace(new RegExp('[^\\d'+sep+']+', 'g'), '')
```

Change it with:

```
val.replace(new RegExp('[^\\d'+sep+'-]+', 'g'), '')
                                    ^
```

Adding the `-` here will mean it won't remove those. `[^\\d'+sep+'-]` will match all characters except digits and the separator. Adding `-` to it means it will not match `-` anymore, and hence, not remove it.

Then this bit matches the number. I'm not entirely sure about it, but I believe you'll need to replace it with something like this:

```
match(new RegExp('(-?\\d+(?:['+sep+']\\d+|))$'));
                   ^^
```

Answer (score 2):

While Jerry's answer addresses the OP's immediate concern, I think there is broader value in understanding why it works, first by understanding what the purpose of the original function was and why the modification resolves the problem.

#### The purpose of the function

1. To change the delimiter  `,` into `.` globally.
2. To eliminate extraneous characters which are neither digits nor decimal delimiters.

The fact that that it converts negative numbers to positive numbers was not its purpose, but rather a side effect of that fact that `-` was not specified as a valid character.

#### What does the function actually do?

The first line above simply figures out whether the decimal delimiter is `.` or `,` because some countries use `,` as a decimal delimiter.

```
    var sep = val.lastIndexOf('.') > val.lastIndexOf(',')? '.' : ',';
```

The second line does two things.

1. It removes all characters except digits and the separator that was detected, by matching them and replacing them with the empty string `''`.
2. It performs a match to verify whether the resulting string looking like a valid number, which is defined to by "one or more digits", optionally followed by a single delimiter together with another valid sequence of digits.

   ```
   var arr = val.replace(new RegExp('[^\\d'+sep+']+', 'g'), '').match(new RegExp('(\\d+(?:['+sep+']\\d+|))$'));
   ```

The third line first checks whether the second line matched successfully, returning `false` if it did not match successfully. If it matched successfully, it will then return the resulting string with all `,` replaced by `.`.

#### Jerry's Fix.

As Jerry correctly described in his answer, the fix is twofold.

1. Add `-` to the set of allowed characters, so that it is not eliminated during the removal of extraneous characters.
2. Add a optional `-` to the beginning of the match clause, so that a negative number will not be rejected by the match.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the detailed explanation and confirming my answer :)